# Reservation.last.card => NoMethodError: undefined method `card' for #<Reservation:0x0090d440e130> Did you mean? card_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm sure it something really stupid, but I cannot seem to find the issue.

I'm trying to call `Reservation.last.card`, but get the error

```
Reservation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" ORDER BY "reservations"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `card' for #<Reservation:0x090d440e130>
Did you mean?  card_id
```

migration + schema

```
class AddCardToReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :reservations, :card, foreign_key: true
  end
end

create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "park_id"
    t.bigint "card_id"
    t.index ["card_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_card_id"
    t.index ["park_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_park_id"
  end
```

models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :card
  belongs_to :park
end

class Card < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :park
  has_many :reservations
end
```

Comment: For starter: Change `has_one :card` to `belongs_to :card`. You may also need to restart your console.

Comment: Thanks Marek, I knew it was something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line in the `Reservation` class...

```
has_one :card
```

Implies that the `card` object has a `reservation_id` which isn't the case, the foreign key is `card_id` in the `reservation` object, so what you want is...

```
belongs_to :card
```